# Accessing LXC root User

Tags: centos, administrator, centos-7, lxc

I am new to containers and am trying figure them out.

I cannot figure out how to log in as root user on the container. I cannot get it to accept the temporary password or to change the password.

(Yes, I am confident I have type the password correctly even though it shows only once in the following output. I have typed the temporary password in myself, had other type it in, and copied and pasted the temporary password in. And have done all the above repeatedly. I delete the other attempts for conciseness.)

Can someone help me get going again?

I am suspicious of a permissions issue, but have not managed to figure out what the permissions are to be...

```
sed: can't read /var/lib/lxc/centostest/rootfs/etc/init/tty.conf: No such file or directory
Storing root password in '/var/lib/lxc/centostest/tmp_root_pass'
chpasswd: cannot open /etc/passwd
Expiring password for user root.
passwd: Libuser error at line: 413 - Error replacing `/etc/passwd': Permission denied.
passwd: Error
```

Here is all the terminal output from container creation through root access attempts and password reset attempts....

```
[root@centos01 ~]# lxc-create -n centostest -t centos
Host CPE ID from /etc/os-release: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Checking cache download in /var/cache/lxc/centos/x86_64/7/rootfs ... 
Cache found. Updating...
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: linorg.usp.br
 * extras: linorg.usp.br
 * updates: linorg.usp.br
No packages marked for update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning repos: base extras updates
0 package files removed
Update finished
Copy /var/cache/lxc/centos/x86_64/7/rootfs to /var/lib/lxc/centostest/rootfs ... 
Copying rootfs to /var/lib/lxc/centostest/rootfs ...
sed: can't read /var/lib/lxc/centostest/rootfs/etc/init/tty.conf: No such file or directory
Storing root password in '/var/lib/lxc/centostest/tmp_root_pass'
chpasswd: cannot open /etc/passwd
Expiring password for user root.
passwd: Libuser error at line: 413 - Error replacing `/etc/passwd': Permission denied.
passwd: Error
sed: can't read /var/lib/lxc/centostest/rootfs/etc/rc.sysinit: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /var/lib/lxc/centostest/rootfs/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit: No such file or directory

Container rootfs and config have been created.
Edit the config file to check/enable networking setup.

The temporary root password is stored in:

        '/var/lib/lxc/centostest/tmp_root_pass'


The root password is set up as expired and will require it to be changed
at first login, which you should do as soon as possible.  If you lose the
root password or wish to change it without starting the container, you
can change it from the host by running the following command (which will
also reset the expired flag):

        chroot /var/lib/lxc/centostest/rootfs passwd

[root@centos01 ~]# vi /var/lib/lxc/centostest/tmp_root_pass
[root@centos01 ~]# lxc-start -n centostest -d
[root@centos01 ~]# lxc-console -n centostest -t 0

Connected to tty 0
                  Type <Ctrl+a q> to exit the console, <Ctrl+a Ctrl+a> to enter Ctrl+a itself

CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 on an x86_64

centostest login: root
Password: 
Login incorrect

centostest login: [root@centos01 ~]# 
[root@centos01 ~]# lxc-stop -n centostest
[root@centos01 ~]# chroot /var/lib/lxc/centostest/rootfs passwd
Changing password for user root.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
[root@centos01 ~]# lxc-start -n centostest -d
[root@centos01 ~]# lxc-console -n centostest -t 0

Connected to tty 0
                  Type <Ctrl+a q> to exit the console, <Ctrl+a Ctrl+a> to enter Ctrl+a itself

CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 on an x86_64

centostest login: root
Password: 
Login incorrect
```

Hardware...

- MB: [Asus M5A97 LE R2.0](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131872)
- CPU: [AMD FX-8370](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA85V4M11432)
- RAM: [G.Skill Sniper DDR3 1866](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231627)
- OS: [CentOS Minimal](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1708.iso)

---

**Later...**

Looking around with `top` shows `systemd-journal` at 100%. When I shutdown the LXC instance that goes away.

So I went to `journalctl`. This is what I see when I `journalctl -f` when I start the instance...

```
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan kernel: virbr3: port 2(vethGC75VP) entered blocking state
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan kernel: virbr3: port 2(vethGC75VP) entered disabled state
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan kernel: device vethGC75VP entered promiscuous mode
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethGC75VP: link is not ready
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan NetworkManager[3741]: <info>  [1519841475.4600] manager: (veth5WRBVL): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/31)
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan NetworkManager[3741]: <info>  [1519841475.4645] manager: (vethGC75VP): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/32)
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethGC75VP: link becomes ready
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan kernel: virbr3: port 2(vethGC75VP) entered blocking state
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan kernel: virbr3: port 2(vethGC75VP) entered forwarding state
Feb 28 13:11:15 centos01.lan NetworkManager[3741]: <info>  [1519841475.4936] device (vethGC75VP): link connected
```

What does not make sense to me is I can see the LXC instance pulling an IP on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Disable selinux temporarily (setenforce 0) and then do an lxc-destroy followed by create.  The create process doesn't play nicely with selinux.